# client.admin.command() run synchronously by default?

Tags: mongodb, asynchronous, synchronization, pymongo

I need to run sh.addShard() in my mongodb cluster. I'm going to use use client.admin.command() for this. But I need to wait until this operation is complete before to continue.

I'd like to know if client.admin.command() wait by default or what's the best way to achieve this behaviour.

In fact (and I know this is another question), does pymongo run all requests synchronously by default? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PyMongo always runs all requests synchronously. (It's not just the "default", PyMongo offers no async mode at all.) Therefore, if you run `command()`, the next line of code won't execute until PyMongo has read MongoDB's response to the command.

Comment: That it seems. The most similar thing I've found is [the multi-process mode](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/faq.html#using-pymongo-with-multiprocessing), but is not the same thing. Anyway, thank you for the aclaration!